# How many disjoint $m$-dimensional subspace in $n$-dimensional space that satisfy the following condition at most?

Tags: linear-algebra

The condition is: any $m+1$ of $m$-dimensional subspaces are disjoint except $\left\{ 0 \right\}$, i.e. they compose a direct sum.

We assume the vector space is over $F_q$, where $q$ is a prime power.

I find an example:

For $q=2$, $m=2$, $n=6$, vector space $V=F_2^6$
$$U_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$U_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$U_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$U_4=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We can see any $3$ of $U_i$ are disjoint and $4$ of them are intersect. But I can't find all the subspace with this property in $V$.

Clearly, the choice of subspace would affect the result. So I want to know what the maximum number of subspace satisfy the condition.

(Please excuse my mistakes in expression and grammar. Thanks)

Comment: Two subspaces can't be disjoint!

Comment: I don‘t understand what you mean. Maybe I use the wrong term? I mean row space of $U_i$ in my example. If i choose $U_5$ consist of the first row in $U_1$ and the first row in $U_2$,  the row space of $U_5$ will intersect with $U_1$ at vector $(1 0 0 0 0 0)$, if any two space have no common vector, i say they are disjoint.

Comment: They always have the $0$ vector in common.

Comment: Yes, except the 0 vector. I should describe more precisely, thank you.

Comment: Can we look at $\Bbb R^n$ for a moment instead? Suppose we're in 3-space, and $m = 2$. You say that "any 3 of the 2-dimensional subspaces are disjoint" and "i.e., they form a direct sum". If we choose 3 planes -- the $xy$, the $xz$, and the $yz$ plane as $U_1, U_2, U_3$, then $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3  = \{0\}$. Is this what you mean by "any 3 are disjoint"? Because although these three planes are, by this definition, "disjoint", they do not form a direct sum, because they are not *pairwise* disjoint. So I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: Of course, in $3$-dimensional space, any $2$ of the $2$-dimensional subspace are intersect, because $3/2<2$. So the dimension of base vector space should be $\geq m(m+1)$. The ''disjoint'' here means all the space are disjoint to each other. For your example, $U_1,U_2,U_3$ should be pairwise disjoint, and $U_1$ should be disjoint to $U_2+U_3$(the space spanned by $U_2$ and $U_3$), and so on... I hope you can understand it. Sorry for my bad description. Or how can I describe it? Thank you for your help.